# Treeview binding to view model not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I looked into all the examples of the Treeview binding, 
  but still I am not able to bind it to Treeview from view model. 
Please let me know what I am missing here.

//This is my class which need to be generated as tree view in UI.

```
public class Station
{        
   public string Name { get; set; } // Header of Treeview

    public ObservableCollection<AnalogToDigital> Adc { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DigitalToAnalog> Dac { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AuxilaryInputs> AuxInput { get; set; }
}

//ADC channel Details
public class AnalogToDigital
{
    public string InternalName { get; set; }               
}

//DAC channel details
public class DigitalToAnalog
{
   public string InternalName { get; set; }

}
//Input output pin details
public class AuxilaryInputs
{       
    public string InternalName { get; set; }            
}
```

//View.xaml: The treeview xaml code:

```
<TreeView Name="StationTree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="326.04" Margin="10,10,0,0"    
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" ItemsSource="{Binding StationTree}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding StationTree}">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>                        
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding StationTree.Adc}">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding StationTree.Adc.InternalName}"/>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                            
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

//ViewModel: I am using mvvmlight here

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Move it to business layer
        StationXmlOperation stRead = new StationXmlOperation();

        StationTree = (Station)stRead.Read(@"C:\Station.xml");           

    }

    private string _name;
    private Station _stationTree;

 public Station StationTree
 {
     get { return _stationTree; }

     set
     {
         _stationTree = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => StationTree);
     }
 }
}
```

//Code behind file : View.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;

        //this.StationTree.DataContext = viewModel.StationTree;
        this.StationTree.Items.Add(viewModel.StationTree);
    }
}
```

//XML file: Station.xml

```
<StationDetails>
<Station id="1" Name="FirstStation">
<ADCs>
<ADC id="1" InternalName="ADC1" ></ADC>
<ADC id="1" InternalName="ADC2" ></ADC>
</ADCs>
<DACs>
<DAC id="1" InternalName="DAC1"  ></DAC>
<DAC id="1" InternalName="DAC2"  ></DAC>
</DACs>
<IOs>
<IO id="1" InternalName="IO1" ></IO>
</IOs>
</Station>
</StationDetails>
```

// Treeview expected from the above object Hierarchy is

```
Name
->ADC
-->InternalName 
->DAC
-->InternalName
->AuxInput
-->InternalName
```

Currently code is displaying only "FirstStation".

Please help me, I am using treeview first time.

Comment: First problem: the property 'StationTree' on your view model is not a collection, it is just an object: 'Station'. You are trying to bind it to an ItemsSource, so it needs to be a collection. Next: your ItemsSource bindings in the HierarchicalDataTemplates are wrong. The DataContext for this is the individual objects making up the original collection your TreeView is bound to, not the ViewModel itself.

Comment: How Can I bind the below class to Treeview. `public class Station
{        
   public string Name { get; set; } // Header of Treeview

    public ObservableCollection<AnalogToDigital> Adc { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DigitalToAnalog> Dac { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AuxilaryInputs> AuxInput { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think xpath is missing in your approach.Create a HDT with xpath

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <Binding XPath="child::*" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>           
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Please follow  [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cbdb2420-1403-436f-aa7f-b1e3b1acb398/binding-any-xml-document-to-wpf-treeview),[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317766/Displaying-XML-in-a-WPF-TreeView),[this](http://www.blogs.intuidev.com/post/2009/12/28/XML_To_TreeView.aspx) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) to know about Treeview with XML Data

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hi, I am not binding to xml directly in View. I want to bind it to Station class object from Viewmodel to view. The above examples explains about direct binding to xml. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to change your object model to make it work with TreeView. As is, it is impossible to make it work with TreeView the way you want, it is just incompatible (you can only bind a HierarchicalDataTemplate to one collection of the child item, you have three collections, and you want each to be nodes of their own).

```
public class Station
{        
    public string Name { get; set; } // Header of Treeview
    public ObservableCollection<DetailGroup> DetailGroups { get; set; }
}

public class DetailGroup
{
    public string GroupName { get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string InternalName { get; set; }               
}

public class ADC : Detail
{
    //...
}

public class DAC : Detail
{
    //...
}

public class AuxInput : Detail
{
    //...
}
```

The object model would basically look like this in XML (this is just an example for you to see the object model, you can keep your original XML the same, you would just need to change your `StationXmlOperation.Read` method):

```
<StationDetails>
  <Station Name="FirstStation">
    <DetailGroup GroupName="ADCs">
      <ADC InternalName="ADC1"/>
      <ADC InternalName="ADC2"/>
    </DetailGroup>
    <DetailGroup GroupName="DACs">
      <DAC InternalName="DAC1"/>
      <DAC InternalName="DAC2"/>
    </DetailGroup>
    <DetailGroup GroupName="AuxInputs">
      <AuxInput InternalName="AuxInput1"/>
      <AuxInput InternalName="AuxInput2"/>
    </DetailGroup>
  </Station>
</StationDetails>
```

Like I mentioned in my comment, you need to bind the ItemsSource of the TreeView to a collection not a single object (if you only have one object, just wrap it in a collection):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Move it to business layer
        StationXmlOperation stRead = new StationXmlOperation();
        _stationTree = (Station)stRead.Read(@"C:\Station.xml");           
    }

    private string _name;
    private Station _stationTree;

    public IEnumerable<Station> StationTree
    {
        get { yield return _stationTree; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding StationTree}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding DetailGroups}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>                        
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>                  
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding InternalName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                            
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```